# Dataflow Batch UTF-8 Conversion

Tags: dataflow, character-encoding

Magento comes with the `Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Abstract` class, which has this method:

```
/**
 * Set batch data
 * automatic convert to serialize data
 *
 * @param mixed $data
 * @return Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Abstract
 */
public function setBatchData($data)
{
    if ('"libiconv"' == ICONV_IMPL) {
        foreach ($data as &$value) {
            $value = iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//IGNORE', $value);
        }
    }

    $this->setData('batch_data', serialize($data));

    return $this;
}
```

This abstract class is extended by `Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Import` (but this method is not changed in that class.)

The problem that I'm having, is that I'm importing from a CSV which is encoded as `MS-ANSI`. So I have extended `Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Import` and replaced the `setBatchData` class to this:

```
/**
 * Set batch data
 * automatic convert to serialize data
 *
 * @param mixed $data
 * @return Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Abstract
 */
public function setBatchData($data) {
    /*
     * This allows parser classes to explicitly set an input encoding
     * The default is utf-8
     */
    $inputEncoding = $this->getCustomInputEncoding();

    if (!empty($inputEncoding)) {
        if (ICONV_IMPL == '"libiconv"' || ICONV_IMPL == 'glibc') {
            foreach ($data as &$value) {
                $value = iconv($inputEncoding, 'utf-8//IGNORE', $value);
            }
        }

        $this->setData('batch_data', serialize($data));

        return $this;
    }

    return parent::setBatchData($data);
}
```

The custom input encoding is assigned by the parser class, like this:

```
$inputEncoding = Mage::getStoreConfig('erp/dataflow_general/input_encoding');    
$batchImportModel = $this->getBatchImportModel()
    ->setId(null)
    ->setBatchId($this->getBatchModel()->getId())
    ->setCustomInputEncoding($inputEncoding)
    ->setBatchData($itemData)
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->save();
```

This seems to do the trick. The problem is that I'm not sure what all is going on under the hood here. For instance, why is `ICONV_IMPL` set to `'"libiconv"'` on my Windows test machine, but set to `'glibc'` on my Linux server?

The [PHP documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/iconv.constants.php) states that `Writing implementation-dependent scripts with these constants is strongly discouraged.` Should I not be checking `ICONV_IMPL` here at all then? Why does Magento check `ICONV_IMPL`?

**Edit:** I'm using the system's available encodings to select which encoding it can try to convert from, through a system config setting. The options for that config setting are as follows:

```
public function toOptionArray() {
        if (empty($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array('utf-8' => 'utf-8');

            $charSets = trim(shell_exec('iconv -l | grep -i ansi'));
            if (!empty($charSets)) {
                $charSets = explode("\n", $charSets);
                $charSets = str_replace("//", '', $charSets);

                foreach ($charSets as $charSet) {
                    $this->_options[ $charSet ] = $charSet;
                }
            }

            asort($this->_options);
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
```

Comment: Short answer, because Windows and Linux use different encoding methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest route**: Re-encode your data file with something to change its encoding to `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1` before importing.

Reason(s):

- http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html
- http://kunststube.net/encoding/

**Alternative route**: Make sure you are using the right value for encoding and is relative to the host OS (obviously).

CLI example of input values for `customInputEncoding`:

`iconv -l | grep -i ansi`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595535/158325

If the PHP docs mention it's bad practice, I'd take heed and reconsider my implementation, regardless if I find it in Magento Core.

Related methods: https://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm already using that shell command to create the system config options for converting encodings. If `MS-ANSI` isn't in that list, it'll just default to `utf-8` which is what Magento does by default anyway. - As for `Writing implementation-dependent scripts` which the docs warn about, I'm not sure that I am, or that I need to. I don't fully understand what all of the options for `ICONV_IMPL` are; only which options I've come across for this one site.

Comment: PS: I looked into `mb_convert_encoding` and couldn't find a compelling reason why it was any better or worse than `iconv`, so I used `iconv` as it's what Magento is already using.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but ran into some similar issues with the OSCommerce migration module: https://github.com/molotovbliss/magento-oscom-migration-tool/commit/4aa602d3be37d1da8e7da6c780f4be3a9808277a